# Проверка условий вхождений символов в строку

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, условия, информатика

"""Алексей составляет таблицу кодовых слов для передачи сообщений, каждому сообщению соответствует своё кодовое слово. В качестве кодовых слов Алексей использует 4-буквенные слова, в которых есть только буквы A, B, C, D, X, причём буква X может появиться на первом месте или не появиться вовсе. Сколько различных кодовых слов может использовать Алексей?""" - условие задачи.
Ответ - 320. По большинству вариантов реализуется через библиотеку intertools:

```py
import itertools
alphabet = "ABCDX"
ar = itertools.product(alphabet, repeat=4) #Размещение с повторением
arl = []
for i in ar:
    arl.append(list(i))
count = 0
for e in arl:
    if (e[0] == 'X' or e[0] != 'X') and e[1] != 'X' and e[2] != 'X' and e[3] != 'X':
        count += 1
print(count) #->320
```

Хотел реализовать через циклы, ручную проверку каждого элемента строки (символа), но по-прежнему выдает те строки, которые не соответствуют условию подстрок:

```py
letters = "ABCDX"
counter = 0
s = ""
for l1 in range(len(letters)):
    for l2 in range(len(letters)):
        for l3 in range(len(letters)):
            for l4 in range(len(letters)):
                s = s + letters[l1] + letters[l2] + letters[l3] + letters[l4]

                if s.count("Х") == 0 or (letters[0] == 'X' and letters[1] != 'X' and letters[2] != 'X'  and letters[3] != 'X'):
                    counter = counter + 1
                    print(counter, ":", s)
                s = ""

print(counter) #->625
```

Извиняюсь за корявый код (хотелось бы реализовать через код выше, если возможно), заранее спасибо.

Comment: А в чём собственно проблема? Вы не хотите сипользовать библиотеку? Если это задача из ЕГЭ, то насколько я знаю там можно использовать стандартные библиотеки, в т.ч. и itertools.

Comment: Хочу ограничиться ограниченным набором библиотек, если это возможно, сведя большинство решений к использованию стандартных операторов, функций с набором полезных классовых методов из строк, например. Да, из ЕГЭ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Немного упростил код и поправил условие проверки (скобки).

```
letters = "ABCDX"
counter = 0
for l1 in letters:
    for l2 in letters:
        for l3 in letters:
            for l4 in letters:
                s = l1 + l2 + l3 + l4

                if (s.count("Х") == 0 or s[0] == 'X') and s[1] != 'X' and s[2] != 'X' and s[3] != 'X':
                    counter += 1
                    print(counter, ":", s)

print(counter)  # ->320
```

Дополнительно. Код с двумя циклами, можно менять количество букв и длину сочетаний.

```
letters = "ABCDX"
base, n_symbols = len(letters), 4
counter = 0
for x in range(base ** n_symbols):
    s, y = '', x
    for n in range(n_symbols):
        y, c = divmod(y, base)
        s += letters[c]
    if (s.count('Х') == 0 or s[0] == 'X') and s[1:4].count('X') == 0:
        counter += 1
        print(f'{counter}: {s}')

print(counter)  # ->320
```

Comment: Эти коварные условия... черт их поймешь.
Огромное спасибо. Так бы не докумекал...

Comment: А как, если несложно, можно реализовать проверку на наличие подряд двух согласных / гласных? """Полина составляет 4-буквенные коды из букв П, О, Л, И, Н, А. Каждую букву можно использовать любое количество раз или совсем не использовать, при этом нельзя ставить подряд две гласные или две согласные. Сколько различных кодов может составить Полина?"""

Comment: import itertools
alphabet = "ПОЛИНА"
vol = "ОИА"
con = "ПЛН"
ar = itertools.product(alphabet, repeat=4) #Размещение с повторением
arl = []
for i in ar:
    arl.append(list(i))
count = 0
for e in arl:
    flag = True
    for i in range(len(e) - 1):
        if (e[i] in vol and e[i + 1] in vol) or (e[i] in con and e[i + 1] in con):
            flag = False
    if flag:
        count += 1
print(count)

Comment: @Naradar Это же другой вопрос, вот и задайте его отдельно. И опять же генерировать строки не нужно

Comment: Первое условие в `if` лишнее.

Answer (score 4):

Для решения этой задачи вовсе не нужно генерировать все строки. (А для больших длин это просто нереально)

Количество строк, начинающихся с Х, равно 4^3, а количество строк без Х равно 4^4. Итого 64+256=320